# Ipad development architecture

Tags: ipad, caching, offlineapps

I have a IPad noob question.

Here is the task I am trying to achieve:

I need to build an IPad/IPhone app that will display a lot of images and data. The problem is that this app needs to work offline as well as online. So, the data needs to stored in some way on the IPad.

I am looking for some opinions on techniques/architecture/development.

To provide a bit of background I work mainly in C#.NET and this is my first IPad app. So far I know that I can either create a native app using objective C, or go for an HTML app which later may or may not be converted to a native app.

Furthermore, I am currently testing by creating a simple html page with an image, and trying to cache the image and page so it will work offline. This so far, however is not working as the image or page do not seem to be cached.

EDIT: Does anyone know how much is the caching limit. I believe I have somewhere around 10-15 mbs of images.

I will appreciate any ideas/opinions/resources on this task.

Answer (score 0):

use CoreData to store your images offline [Apple CoreData Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

I am unsure wot you need the online bit for, are you retrieving images off the net or uploading them?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Retrieving them for later use. There are around 5000 images that need to be displayed offline.

Comment: Is it possible to access the CoreData from a web application?